# How to run a number of task repeatedly and stop it after a certain amount of time in java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice

I've seen a here and there part's of my answer but not a complete one.

I know that if you want tu run multiple task at the same time you want to use `Thread` with `Runnable` implementation

I've seen that you can use the `ScheduledExecutorService` if you want to run repetitive tasks like this :

```
Runnable helloRunnable = () -> System.out.println("Hello world " + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime().toString());
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But this run just one thread and does not have method or parameter to kill the process after a certain time

What I would like to do is to run 5time the same task in parallel every 10seconds for 10minutes

---

**Edit**

If future people are interested in full example of it here it is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable helloRunnable = () -> System.out.println("Hello world " + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime().toString());
    Runnable testRunnable = () -> System.out.println("Test runnable " + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime().toString());

    List<Runnable> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    taskList.add(helloRunnable);
    taskList.add(testRunnable);

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    List <ScheduledFuture<?>> promiseList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Runnable runnable : taskList) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> promise = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        promiseList.add(promise);
    }

    List <Runnable> cancelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ScheduledFuture<?> promise : promiseList) {
        Runnable cancelRunnable = () -> {
            promise.cancel(false);
            executor.shutdown();
        };
        cancelList.add(cancelRunnable);
    }

    List <ScheduledFuture<?>> canceledList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Runnable runnable : cancelList){
        ScheduledFuture<?> canceled = executor.schedule(runnable, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        canceledList.add(canceled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR: Schedule another task to cancel the first.

First things first, **don't ignore return values** - this is bad habit to get into, stop doing it and practice not doing it. The method [`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) returns a `ScheduledFuture<?>` - this allows you to cancel the task!

So, to run the task every `10` seconds for `1` minute:

```
final Runnable helloRunnable = () -> System.out.println("Hello world " + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime().toString());
final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
final ScheduledFuture<?> promise = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
final ScheduledFuture<Boolean> canceller = executor.schedule(() -> promise.cancel(false), 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

---

Another thing to note, is that if you never call `get` on the `Future` you never know if the task fails - that means you need *another* `Thread` to wait on `promise.get` so that if an `Exception` is thrown you know immediately that something has gone wrong.

Then then question is [who monitors the monitoring threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F). So you quickly find yourself reimplementing a task scheduling library if you want something robust.

---

Also note the useful utility method `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`.

Comment: As you said the issue is that the canceller itself is not canceled and is still running so you still have that issue :/

Comment: @user3718160 why? It runs **once** after `1` minute - `schedule` rather than `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Comment: I did just a small example to see how it works and if i run the thread once every second then stop it after 10 second. Although the print stop, The program doesn't, it's still continue to run indefinitively in iddle

Comment: That's because you need to shutdown the executor. That's a different question about daemon vs non daemon threads. TBH as you were asking above more advanced threading topics I assumed you knew that and the example was illustrative - otherwise you have some reading to do.

Comment: Ok but then how do you shutdown the executor at the end of the run ?

Comment: Stick a `shutdown` in the cancel task. Or block your main method on `canceller.get` and call shutdown when it returns. Although that only works for this simple example